# Web2py BigInt showing up as 0. Bigint_id=True

Tags: integer, web2py

I set in DAL(bigint_id=True) since my itemNumber field is being used as primary key in other tables as well.  In one particular table, i'm using it as a unique field but not as primary key

```
mydb.define_table('myitems', 
                    Field('id', 'id',notnull=True,unique=True),
                    Field('itemNumber', 'bigint',notnull=True,unique=True),
                    Field('uniqueTitle', 'string'),
```

When trying to insert, it always inserts as "0".
However, when i print that row, i would see the proper number: example 111078127801

```
mydb.myitems.update_or_insert(mydb.myitems.itemNumber==int(row),
                              uniqueTitle=fileName)
```

I did a print int(row) and print row and both show up the proper value.
It's during insertion that forces it to 0.
I have both tried specifying  Field('itemNumber' as bigint and integer and both with the same results.

Thanks,

John

Comment: Your `.update_or_insert` statement isn't inserting a value for itemNumber at all -- it is simply updating the uniqueTitle field for any records whose itemNumber matches `int(row)`. On an insert, I would think you would get a database error given that no itemNumber has been specified and you have `notnull=True` (though if you added `notnull=True` after the original table creation, I'm not sure if that constraint would be updated in the database).

Comment: What's the proper way of using .update_or_insert to have it insert row to itemNumber if it was to perform an insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
mydb.myitems.update_or_insert(mydb.myitems.itemNumber==int(row),
                              itemNumber=int(row), uniqueTitle=fileName)
```

If the first argument is a query, it simply selects the records to be updated (if any). You must still specify all of the field values that you want to insert/update.